# Improve readability of object name in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

### Context

Given that the convention for naming an object on **Rails** is like that :

```
/app/models/foo/bar.rb => class Foo::Bar
```

if I have a folder structure :

```
/app/models/foo/bar/object1.rb
/app/models/foo/bar/object2.rb
/app/models/foo/main.rb
```

To call this objects from my main, I have to do :

```
class Foo::Main

  def some_method
    Foo::Bar::Object1.new
    Foo::Bar::Object2.new
  end

end
```

This work fine. But here my question :

### Question

Is there a way to improve the **readability of the name of object** ?

Given that in my `Foo::Main` is in the same namespace `Foo`; Is there a way to call them (`Foo::Bar::Object1.new` and `Foo::Bar::Object2.new`) with a shorter name ?

I would like to name them `Bar::Object1.new` and `Bar::Object2.new`, in this context (or `Object1.new` and `Object2.new`)

### Expected

```
class Foo::Main

  def some_method
    Bar::Object1.new
    Bar::Object2.new
  end

end
```

This code is an exemple of what I'm expected, but it don't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use the top module, you need to use nesting without the `A::B` shorthand:

```
module Foo
  class Main

    def some_method
      Bar::Object1.new
      Bar::Object2.new
    end
  end
end
```

Sources:

- https://blog.honeybadger.io/avoid-these-traps-when-nesting-ruby-modules/
- https://techblog.thescore.com/2014/05/28/how-you-nest-modules-matters-in-ruby/

Answer (score 0):

if you're interested in learning more about best practices on syntax I'd suggest using a tool like Rubocop: https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop

Whether you end up making it apart of your workflow or not doesn't really matter. That said, it is hugely helpful in identifying best practices to improve your codes maintainability/readability and helps a lot when working on teams.