# Code Style Ruby Style/ClassAndModuleChildren

Tags: ruby, rubocop

I'm trying to follow Ruby code styles, and I got a warning regarding "Code Style Ruby Style/ClassAndModuleChildren" for this declaration:

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController
```

How can I unbundle that? Checking with [Rubocop (VSCode Extension)](https://rubocop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cops_style/#styleclassandmodulechildren), I could not identify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use explicit module nesting:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class UsersController < ApplicationController
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you share what code style the community usually uses? Nested ou flattened? It seems the flattened is not that bad.

Comment: It's rather nested, because of issues described in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54257918/improve-readability-of-object-name-in-rails/54258010#54258010